# How do you test JavaScript errors with Selenium WebDriver and NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, selenium

I'm using JavaScript, not Java here. But, for example, if I am running a particular website, say foo.com, I will set it up like:

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
var path = require("chrome");

var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser("chrome")
    .build()

driver.get("foo.com");
```

I am interested in catching non-Selenium based errors. So for example, this is an error I see pretty often that I'd like to test for:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'testVariable' of undefined
at test.js:27
```

How do I grab the site specific errors? I'd like to create a function that helps me with it. Maybe something like:

```
var seekErrors = function(){
    return driver.(some function to get a list of js errors or things output to the console)
}
```

Is there anything like this in Selenium WebDriver? If so, I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at DesiredCapabilities within Selenium and the LoggingPref object.

More info on the [SeleniumHQ wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities).

Here is an [example using it in Firefox](https://advancedweb.hu/2016/03/29/selenium-tes-logs/)